# openssl hmac using aes-256-cbc

Tags: openssl, aes, hmac

I am trying to take an AES HMAC of a file using the `openssl` command line program on Linux.  I have been looking at the man pages but can't quite figure out how successfully make a HMAC.  I can encrypt a file using the `enc` command  with `openssl` however I can't seem to create a HMAC.  The encryption looks like the following:

```
openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -in plaintext -out ciphertext
```

Any advice or tutorials would be wonderful

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You may be asking about [CBC-MAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CBC-MAC).  For that, I think you just encrypt your message or file with an IV of 0 and then take the last block (16 bytes for AES256-cbc).  [I found a blog post](http://www.clinicallyawesome.com/2009/07/cbc-mac-on-command-line.html) that describes how to do this with OpenSSL:

```
openssl enc -e -aes-256-cbc -K 0123456789ABCDEF -iv 0000000000000000 < file | tail -c 16 | od -A n
```

- `-K` is where you provide your key, which the wiki page says should be different than what you're using to encrypt the file, if you're encrypting it at all.
- `-iv` obviously provides an all-zero IV, which is the key for CBC-MAC.
- The `tail -c 16` is to get the last AES256-cbc block, which is 16-bytes long.
- `od` is to convert it to hex, which that web site says is common.  Otherwise instead of `od -A n` you could do `base64` if that's more applicable, or leave it off completely to have just the raw bytes.

---

You can't take an AES HMAC of a file because AES256-cbc is a block cipher, not a hashing algorithm.  AES256-cbc is for encrypting and decrypting a file.  HMAC is for verifying a file's integrity and requires a hash algorithm at its core such as SHA-1 or MD5.

Are you trying to sign or verify a file, or encrypt it?  To sign, check out the [OpenSSL dgst](http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/dgst.html) command and use simple HMACs like MD5 or SHA-1, or go all out and digitally sign it with DSS/DSA.

Also, I believe using a block cipher as a MAC is called an [EMAC](http://search.cpan.org/~jcduque/Digest-EMAC-1.2/EMAC.pm), but OpenSSL doesn't do EMAC as far as I know.  EMAC just takes the last block of an encrypted file and encrypts it to create a MAC.

Comment: Perhaps I misspoke in my original question; I need the MAC of an AES cipher-text.  Does this make more cryptographic sense?  I believe the MAC of AES is just the last encrypted block, yes?

Comment: @Ryan:  I added some info on CBC-MAC.  Hope it helps.  If that's not what you mean either, perhaps you can give more background on why you need to compute this AES MAC.  Is this part of a well-known protocol?  What are you going to do with it once you compute it?  Broader background info might help someone else to jump in and provide the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can perform an HMAC of a file using an AES key as input to the HMAC.

Encrypt the file using any AES algorithm you want (in this example -aes-256-cbc); generate an AES key based on a password (change "password" to your password) and use the -p switch to dump the salt, key, and iv used to encrypt.

```
openssl enc -e -k password -p -aes-256-cbc -in plaintext -out ciphertext
salt=A2402067B9BFD4A1
key=EB3A88115C30F26C3987F1AB2577DF5B58C80EBEEA623506517FAD843C64E1FC
iv =B382453BCBF579CE14C0726D343F40E2
```

Create an HMAC of any object/file using a hash algorithm of your choice and the AES key that was used to encrypt the file:

```
openssl dgst -hmac EB3A88115C30F26C3987F1AB2577DF5B58C80EBEEA623506517FAD843C64E1FC -sha256 ciphertext
HMAC-SHA256(ciphertext)= fa3fb9c9c743f35ba81793e2704c3fc9737cd2675011110cb1655ea7ceed2914
```

Remember the AES key for use later if you need to verify the HMAC. Note that I do not know what you are trying to accomplish and I cannot claim the above meets your cryptographic requirements, but it does show how to encrypt a file, obtain the encryption key, and use that encryption key in an HMAC computation.